# padding-bottom is not working. I'm testing in chrome browser

Tags: css, html

Sorry for messing my code soo much.this is my first experiment. Doing it all with the help of google. So, Can you tell me how to write the following code in an efficient way and also, I want to pull the text up in the heading block. Help me.[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    seVen
</title>
    <style>body{background:#A8A8A8;color:white;}
   .heading{background:#303030;position:fixed;border-radius: 25px;top:10px;
        right:2px;left:2px;bottom:85%;padding:10px;}
   .login{position:relative;float:right;top:150px;bottom:145px;}
   .padding{padding-left:30px;padding-bottom:30px;position:relative;}
    </style>

<div class="heading"><div class="padding"><p style="font size:30px">seVen</p><p style="font-size:15px">Own your imagination</p></div></div>
<body>
<div class="login">
Enter your name  &nbsp;<input type="text" id="name" /><br><br>

Password &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="password" id="password" />

<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="button" id="pwdForgot" value="Forgot Password"/></head>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><hr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Products

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when you say you want to 'pull the text up the heading block' what do you actually mean? Is the 'own your imagination' text supposed to be in the heading?

Comment: Yes.Both "seVen" and "Own your imagination" should be in that heading block.@GKB

Comment: Efficient? the only thing i see is `<br>` and `&nbsp;` thats not exactly the way to do it. I would suggest you start checking w3schools for basic css styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the height of `.heading` is based on `position:fixed;top:10px;bottom:85%` which makes it a specific height which changes as you resize the page vertically. You could replace `bottom` with `height` and it will look more consistent.

You can then add line-height to put the text in the middle of the block:

```
.heading{
  background: #303030;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 85%
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

---

## Other suggestions:

You may consider changing fixed positioning (`position:fixed;top:10px;right:2px;left:2px;`) to specific widths and margins:

```
.heading{
  background: #303030;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  width: 98%;
  margin: 1%
}
```

The differences with removing `position:fixed` is it won't scroll with the screen, and it will push everything else on the page below it.

---

Also, instead of using `<br><br><br>...` and `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...` try setting margin and padding:

```
<div style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:50px">Own your imagination</div>
```

(you may find `display:inline-block`, `float:left`, or `float:right` useful at this point if you end up changing the page a lot using these)

---

And your footer could make use of `position:fixed` if you want it to stick to the bottom of the page, something like:

```
<div style="position:fixed;bottom:10px;left:0;right:0;border-top:solid 1px white">
    <a class="padding">About</a>
    <a class="padding">Products</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `margin-bottom`

Example:

```
.heading .padding
{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few very major issues with your markup:

1. Your `div` with class `heading` is outside of your `body` tag - all the content in your html file should be within your body tags.
2. Your `head` tag closes near the bottom of your document - the `head` tag always needs to close before your opening `body` tag.
3. You can't rely on `&nbsp;` characters and `br` tags to space your content - You need to use padding and margins.

You should find that once you've re-structured everything, that some of your issues should be fixed.

Also, the main reason that your 'own your imagination' text isn't on the same line, is because by default `p` tags will always start a new line.

Follow this basic `html` layout to restructure what you've got so far, following my points above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <title></title>
   </head>
   <style>
   </style>
   <body>
      <!-- all your content needs to go in here -->
   </body>
 </html>
```

And then in your header, if you change your `p` tags to `span` tags and give them a style of `display: inline-block`, you'll be able to space them how you would like with some padding.

Also, generally speaking, it's better practice to link to an external stylesheet instead of using inline styles or including your css in `style` tags in the head, but concentrate on what you've got so far.When you feel confident, you can have a look at this:

[Linking to an External Stylesheet](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

I also highly recommend using [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/) as a general resource going forwards, there's some great stuff on there that should really help with structuring and layout.